# How to find intersection of straight lines with Hough Peaks?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, houghlinesp

I am developing a method to localise license plate and ultimately apply perspective transform to straighten the plate horizontally.

Currently, my image processing pipeline is able to roughly locate the plate but I'd like to narrow it further. I have applied edge detection, morphological operations and connected component analysis to get to this stage.

My result for license plate detection currently is this

[image]

I am trying to implement HoughLinesP to find straight lines of the fonts and then find the intersection of the lines with HoughPeaks, like this

[image]

My current attempt at finding houghlines is shown at the code below. However, can anyone guide me on how to find hough peaks? I did some research online and couldn't find any reliable reference.

```
def findHoughLines(self, image):
    from src.Line import Line

    # Add 1 channel to binary image
    image = image[..., np.newaxis]
    vis = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    canny = cv2.Canny(image, 100, 200)

    cv2.imshow("canny", canny)

    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(canny, rho=0.01, theta=np.pi/360, threshold=10, minLineLength=100, maxLineGap=30)

    print(len(lines))
    linesHorizontal, linesVertical = [], []

    if lines is None:
        print("[Info] No Hough lines have been detected")
        return image

    for line in lines:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
        if abs(x1 - x2) > abs(y1 - y2):
            linesHorizontal.append(Line(line[0]))
        else:
            linesVertical.append(Line(line[0]))

    # sort lines
    linesHorizontal = sorted(linesHorizontal, key=lambda l: l.d_y, reverse=True)[:10]
    linesVertical = sorted(linesVertical, key=lambda l: l.d_x, reverse=True)[:10]

    for line in linesHorizontal:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line.points
        cv2.line(vis, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 1)

    for line in linesVertical:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line.points
        cv2.line(vis, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 1)

    cv2.imshow("HoughLines", vis)
```

Result of HoughLinesP Detection

[image]

Comment: Hough peaks is just the peaks in the hough matrix, or in other words the ones that passes certain amount of votes in the accumulator... In `HoughLinesP` this is already done, and it returns the lines which pass the threshold of votes given in the function (in your code you give 5)

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Do you think there is a better approach to my problem?

Comment: I haven't done much in the license plate recognition area, but I think that you can try to find contours, and get the bottom coordinate of each contour, and try to create a line that fits (with certain tolerance) to the bottom points of each contour (maybe with RANSAC), do the same with top of the contours, the letters/numbers have a fixed height and you can use this baseline to know which contours are letters. Then you put all the points together and use minAreaRect (or something like that) which gives you even the angle that you need to rotate the image to make it straight

Comment: Thanks! That’s very insightful! Will try it out